# Printing images in a loop

Tags: qt, qpainter, qprinter

I've been trying to print out a whole folder of images as the first stage of a project and haven't been able to get it working. The images are named "batch_X.jpg" (but the file type can change if something works better) and for testing I've been just having it print to pdf, to not waste thousands of pieces of paper. I can get the loop to go to completion and make files named "testX" to an output folder, however instead of them being the image I want to print, they always just show up as blank white pages.

Here is the code as I have been running it, complete with lines commented out all over the place

```
QApplication app(int argc, char** argv());
    for (int q = 1; q <= 11; q++)
    {
    //int q = 4;
   QString fileName=QStringLiteral("/Users/user/Desktop/imageTests⁩/output/batch_%1.jpg").arg(q);         
            // QPrinter printer;
            //QPrintDialog *dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer,0);
            //if(dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
            QPrinter printer(QPrinter::ScreenResolution);
            printer.setResolution(3000);
            //printer.setPageLayout(page_layout);
            printer.setCopyCount(1);
            printer.setDoubleSidedPrinting(false);
            printer.setDuplex(QPrinter::DuplexNone);
            printer.setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
            printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::Letter);
            printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::Letter);
            printer.setPaperSource(QPrinter::Auto);
            //printer.setCreator("Inkjet Plumber");
            printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
            printer.setPageMargins(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, QPrinter::Inch);
            //printer.setPageLayout(page_layout);
            QString outputFileName =              QStringLiteral("/Users/user/Desktop/testing/test%1.pdf").arg(q);
            printer.setOutputFileName(outputFileName);
                    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
                    QImage img(fileName);
                    QPainter painter(&printer);
                    painter.drawImage(QPoint(0,0),img);
                    painter.end();
                    //QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Title"), QString(fileName));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.
It works on my side.
The only thing I would fix is resolution:

```
 printer.setResolution(300);
```

Comment: And you are getting outputs that aren't just blank white pages, but actually the picture you input?

Comment: Alright I got it working. My problem now is the image is much smaller than it originally was, and only takes up a small portion of the page, compared to being full size originally. The sizing is very important so it needs to take up the full page. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: > the image is much smaller than it originally was

That's why printer.setResolution(300); helped me.
You have to set DPI (Dots Per Inch) value according the pages size in Inches and image size in Pixels (Dots)